# Use config file for python in docker container

Tags: python, docker

I have a docker container with a python application in it. The application needs the path of a config file as an command line argument:

```
$ python MyApp.py config.json
```

My docker file looks like this

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.6-slim

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
ADD . /app

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

# Make port 80 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 80

# Run app.py when the container launches
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

How can I pass the command line argument for the config file to the application inside the docker container? The directory with the config file is inside the container:

```
ContainerDir
    -> app.py
    -> Dockerfile
    -> Config/config.json
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the `docker run` command, anything after the image name will be parsed as `[COMMAND] [ARGS...]`.

In your case, you can use the following `docker run` command to pass extra arguments to your program.

```
docker run <image>:<tag> python app.py Config/config.json
```

P.S. Docker run reference: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I found another solution, which works too. For this I map the directory in the container and pass the path:

      docker run -v <Path>/Config/config.json:/Config/config.json <Container> -c Config/config.json